# pg_dump: No matching schemas were found

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump, case-sensitive

I am trying to dump a schema from Postgres 9.4, running on Cents 6.5, but I get an error:

> pg_dump: No matching schemas were found

Here is the command I am running:

```sh
pg_dump -U postgres -n "OLD-TODELETE-bushes" --verbose site > output_nf
```

I am a little confused by this as when I run `select schema_name from information_schema.schemata`, I can see the schema name.

If I run pg_dump for all schemas the `OLD-TODELETE-bushes` is dumped to file, as expected.

There are no error's in the Postgres logs.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try it without the quotes around the schema name? I suppose that you did the `pg_dump` for all schema's with the same user and for the same database (`site`)?

Comment: Yeah tried it with and without quotes and with same user, same db...  Works fine for every other schema in the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed this by changing the quotes from `"schema_name"` to `'"schema_name"'`

See: [pg_dump doesn't dump datascheme with uppercase letters in](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200702261154.l1QBsXxv082562@wwwmaster.postgresql.org)

...where Tom Lane [replied](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3683.1172511792@sss.pgh.pa.us):

> The problem is that there are two levels of quoting needed: one for the shell and one for SQL.  As you wrote it, the double quotes are stripped off by the shell and so pg_dump gets Schema, which is case-folded per normal SQL rules.  So you need to write:
>
> ```
> pg_dump -n '"Schema"' -U postgres database
> ```
>
> Now, the shell eats the single quotes and passes "Schema" to pg_dump.

Comment: Important to note (like Tom Lane did, too): this is not a bug, just your missing quotes. My standing advice is no use legal lower-case identifiers in Postgres and never have to deal with such problems.